# Как использовать свою джава библиотеку в дженкинс пайплайне

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Есть библиотека запушенная на гитхаб, хотелось бы как-то использовать ее в пайплайне

```
@Library('test') _

@Library('test') _
import com.bla.bla.Bla

@Library('test') import com.bla.bla.Bla
```

Это все выдает **unable to resolve class Bla**.
Вообще возможно ли это, и что может быть не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Из коробки" дженкинс не позволяет использовать Java библиотеки в DSL скриптах (пайплайнах). Описанный вами синтаксис служит для подключения [Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) к пайплайну.

Есть некоторый "воркэраунд", если уж очень сильно хочется использовать классы из своей библиотеки. Можно положить в репозиторий скомпиленный `.class` и вызывать его через `java yourClass etc`.

Есть ещё более "хардкорный" вариант: положить в Shared Library в раздел `resources/` некомпиленные `.java` файлы, а в `src/` положить groovy скрипт, в котором сделать обвязку, на компил и запуск вашего класса. В пайплайне подключаете Shared Library описанным вами способом и вызываете groovy скрипт, который за вас скомпилит и запустит Java класс.